# IIS Files not Being Updated on Upload?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

I have an odd quirk in my IIS server. I have an ASP.NET 4.5 application pool that I upload an MVC website onto using FTP publishing in Visual Studio. The odd thing is, when I go and look on the files in the server (i.e., the inetpub folder), some of the files are old, or not there altogether.

For example, I had altered a controller class and added a few views and methods to access them. The views uploaded, but the controller stayed the same. Yet on the site, I was able to access the new views.

I've tagged this with a bunch of different things, as I'm not sure if this is happening somewhere in Visual Studio, or on the server.

Any idea why this happens/what I can do to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: The files that didn't upload, are they all code files? They may be ignored in favor of a compiled version of the project.

Comment: The are indeed code files...but they're from the web project. I understand the library projects are compiled into dll's, but the web project should remain as .cs and .cshtml files, no?

Answer (score 1):

Code files and controllers get compiled into your `bin` folder as dlls. The dll is then used by your application.

If you publish or deploy, VS is smart enough to know not to copy these files over.

Comment: I'm having a bit of a time understanding the process, now. So, if my entire application is compiled into a DLL (which makes sense), then why (even if just by default) does Visual Studio upload the entire project, with the views and controllers, image source files, and everything else? There's also a number of periphery files (such as the Global.asax and Web.Config) that get published, too.

Comment: @Jack The main things that need to come over in order for your site to work are bin, content, scripts, views, global.asax, and web.config. I'm actually slightly confused now as in the question you had said your controllers (code files) weren't being updated. They aren't supposed to be there anyway and VS shouldn't publish them.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why it publishes that, but I haven't changed any of the publish settings, and it published every folder that's in the web project (nothing that's in the DLL library project or the test project that's in the same solution, though).